# converting jacoco.exec error

Tags: java, ant, jacoco

Im trying to convert/use jacoco.exec that i genereated before. I am using a build.xml found on google. In my dir folder I have the following files in my dir folder :

```
    build.xml   CompareNumbers.class  jacoco.exec  src
build.xml~  jacocoant.jar         Main.class   TestCompareNumbers.class
```

Also, src folder contains my java classes :

```
CompareNumbers.java  Main.java  TestCompareNumbers.java
```

My build.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
   Copyright (c) 2009, 2015 Mountainminds GmbH & Co. KG and Contributors
   All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
   are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
   which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
   http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html

   Contributors:
      Marc R. Hoffmann - initial API and implementation
-->
<project name="Example Ant Build with JaCoCo" default="rebuild" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">

    <description>
      Example Ant build file that demonstrates how a JaCoCo coverage report
      can be itegrated into an existing build in three simple steps.
    </description>

    <property name="src.dir" location="./src"/>
    <property name="result.dir" location="./"/>
    <property name="result.classes.dir" location="${result.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="result.report.dir" location="${result.dir}/site/jacoco"/>
    <property name="result.exec.file" location="${result.dir}/jacoco.exec"/>

    <!-- Step 1: Import JaCoCo Ant tasks -->
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="./jacocoant.jar"/>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${result.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${result.classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${result.classes.dir}" debug="true" includeantruntime="false"/>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="compile">
        <!-- Step 2: Wrap test execution with the JaCoCo coverage task -->
        <jacoco:coverage destfile="${result.exec.file}">
            <java classname="org.jacoco.examples.parser.Main" fork="true">
                <classpath path="${result.classes.dir}"/>
                <arg value="2 * 3 + 4"/>
                <arg value="2 + 3 * 4"/>
                <arg value="(2 + 3) * 4"/>
                <arg value="2 * 2 * 2 * 2"/>
                <arg value="1 + 2 + 3 + 4"/>
                <arg value="2 * 3 + 2 * 5"/>
            </java>
        </jacoco:coverage>
    </target>

    <target name="report" depends="test">
        <!-- Step 3: Create coverage report -->
        <jacoco:report>

            <!-- This task needs the collected execution data and ... -->
            <executiondata>
                <file file="${result.exec.file}"/>
            </executiondata>

            <!-- the class files and optional source files ... -->
            <structure name="JaCoCo Ant Example">
                <classfiles>
                    <fileset dir="${result.classes.dir}"/>
                </classfiles>
                <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                    <fileset dir="${src.dir}"/>
                </sourcefiles>
            </structure>

            <!-- to produce reports in different formats. -->
            <html destdir="${result.report.dir}"/>
            <csv destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.csv"/>
            <xml destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.xml"/>
        </jacoco:report>
    </target>

    <target name="rebuild" depends="clean,compile,test,report"/>

</project>
```

Unfortunately, every time when i run "ant report" or ant compile, the following error is raised :

```
    /home/luci/workspace/dir/build.xml:26: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/jacocoant.jar!/org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml:19: taskdef A class needed by class org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask cannot be found: org/jacoco/core/analysis/ICoverageVisitor
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[/home/luci/workspace/dir/jacocoant.jar]
```